# HibernateSearch query

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am new to hibernate Search and i find difficulty in forming Hibernateserach query.
I need to use IN opeartor to the List the String in Hibernate query . 
Can anybody help me to sort out this issue.
My current query look like this

```
String querystring="country:"+profile.getCountry()+" AND religion:"+profile.getReligion()+"  AND caste:"+profile.getCaste()+" AND gender:"+profile.getGender()+"AND profession : "+professions+" AND age:["+profile.getFromage()+" TO "+profile.getToage()+"]" ;
```

here is professions is a list of string.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

There is no *IN* operator in Lucene query language. You will have to expand the string yourself. An alternative for using the query parser would be to use a Lucene *BooleanQuery* and add the different parts of your query to it, for example a *RangeQuery* etc. Effectively the QueryParser creates under the hood this lower level queries for you. Have a look at the Lucene API and the different sub classes of *org.apache.lucene.search.Query*. You still have to expand the collection string yourself though. 
Last but not least, you could use the Hibernate Search query DSL. Have a look at the online docs of Hibernate Search if you want to know more - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the following clauses to your query SELECT, FROM, and WHERE. Also the conditions are missing parts. For example here is a valid query. "SELECT e from Employee where e.country = :country and e.religion = :religion"...

Comment: Hi Manuel thanks for your reply. I am creating a lucene querystring. I need to just parse these string then internally Lucene query will handle the select , from clauses I am using HibernateSearch  The complete code is as shown below

Comment: The querystring works fine with the following string   String querystring="country:"+profile.getCountry()+" AND religion:"+profile.getReligion()+"  AND caste:"+profile.getCaste()+" AND gender:"+profile.getGender()+" AND age:["+profile.getFromage()+" TO "+profile.getToage()+"]" ;  but when i add list professions it will not work  Thanks Arun

Comment: You may want to add that this is for lucene to your question.  I have added the lucene tag to your question